# how to edit visual studio font color customization

Tags: fonts, customization, vscode-extensions

I have been trying to change the color of const and console.log from white to blue on my mac laptop

I went to the settings  of my vs code and tried editing the font Ligatures and token color customizations but still couldn't figure it out